# Unable to load memcached.so on GAE Flexible environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached, app-engine-flexible

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel 5.2 app on GAE Flexible environment. I'm getting the following error there.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/php56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcached.so'
>   - /opt/php56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/memcached.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0

AFAIK, it is using `gcr.io/google_appengine/php:latest` docker image. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github repo has a Pull request for this issue.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-sidecars-docker/pull/19

> Some clients use Memcached::getVersion to determine if the server is running and the connection is working. The current implementation throws an error, which results in clients making the mistaken assumption the server is not responding.